# 100 result limit from Splunk API call

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests, splunk

I should be getting around 1000 results, but it this is only returning 100 of them into the output file.

```
g = requests.get(base_url + '/services/search/jobs/' + sid + '/results/',

headers = {'Authorization':('Splunk %s' %session_key)},data={'output_mode': 'json', 'count':'0'},  verify = False)

data = g.json()

names = [item['name'] for item in data['results']]

with open ('sOutput.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,  delimiter='\n', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow(names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTTP spec, `GET` requests don't contain a request body ([relevant Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)), which is what you're define with the `data` parameter of the `requests.get()` method ([relevant Real Python blog post](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-message-body) explaining this). Splunk's [API documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/RESTREF/RESTprolog) also specifically refers to these options as "parameters for [...] `GET` methods".

Use `request.get()`'s `params` argument instead to correctly pass these options along to the server:

```
g = requests.get(base_url + '/services/search/jobs/' + sid + '/results/',

headers = {'Authorization':('Splunk %s' %session_key)},params={'output_mode': 'json', 'count':'0'},  verify = False)

data = g.json()

names = [item['name'] for item in data['results']]

with open ('sOutput.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,  delimiter='\n', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow(names)
```

As an aside, you may find it useful to familiarize yourself with the [Requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master), more specifically with the [Passing Parameters in URLs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) section.